# How to get to Torch on Moto G / Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g, user-interface

I have two copies of Motorola Moto G with (now) Marshmallow 6.0.1. One of them has recently "removed" Torch icon from notification area:

[image]

Now, I don't have access to it at all. Neither in Settings menu, nor among installed apps.

How can I start it on the other phone or how can I "reset" notification area on the other phone to the same state like previously / like on the first phone?

**EDIT**: I have enabled and made use of *System UI Tuner* > *Quick Settings*, but it brought no help. I can see *Torch* icon enabled there, but I still don't see it in quick access area, where I saw it just a week ago and for the past year or so.

The same story goes for *Broadcast Title* and *Invert colours* icons, which I can add to my layout in *System UI Tuner* > *Quick Settings*, but which actually never appear in quick access area.

I have just made a test photo with flash light enabled to double check that there are no hardware issues that could be causing *Torch* icon to disappear.

My current system:

- Android version: **6.0.1**.
- Android security patch level: **1 September 2017**.
- Baseband version: **M8916_20250106.08.05.14.02R HARPIA_APAC_DSDS_CUST**.
- Kernel version: **3.10.49-g5531188 hudsoncm@ilclbld71 #1 Mon Sep 25 05:50:06 CDT 2017**.
- Build number: **MPIS24.241-15.3-26**.

*Exactly the same* on both devices that I own.

Comment: Does it allow you to edit the layout when you press and hold the gear icon top-right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an [old problem cited two years ago](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-X-1st-Gen/Flashlight-missing-from-Quick-Settings/m-p/3174102#M26145) wherein torch light and cast icons as in case of OP go missing. Reason attributed is some icons disappear if not used for long and reboot brings them back as it happened in OP's case.

Probably this is a bug that is continuing and not found in latter models - I don't see that on Moto X Play (also maybe because I use  Gravity box Xposed module interface for quick settings)

It sounds stupid, but it looks like you have to remember to use those icons to be able to find them when you need them :(