# Missing auto-rotate icon

Tags: user-interface, auto-rotation

About 6 days ago my auto-rotate function icon disappeared on my old cheap Moto E.

Is there somewhere in the menu structure which talks about auto-rotate? I just cannot see anything.

I have looked around online and short of downloading another app and switching on and off, have not seen anything relevant.

TIA Steve

Comment: This may help https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187678/131553

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Don't think it is exactly on point but, finally, I have found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto rotate IS there but in Accessibility - somewhere I had not thought of looking.

Inevitably found this on Google. I had tried a hundred different questions but finally found the right one,

Hopefully this will be useful for someone in the dim distant future.

If this fixes your problem please up vote.

(PS The presence or absence of icons depends on usage so it might go missing again but now you know where to find it I hope!)