# Missing Cast icon in the Notification Center

Tags: windows, screencast, samsung-galaxy-j7

I mean to cast my Android screen to my Windows 10 PC.
I pull down from the top, but I do not find the *Cast* icon, even if I pull a second time.

**Can I fix this?**

Using Android 8.1.0 (Oreo) in a J7 Prime.

Note 1:

- Accroding to [this](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9083864), "Some of these steps work only on Android 10 and up."
  There isn't any further specification.
- According to [this](https://androidcommunity.com/how-to-customizing-android-oreos-quick-settings-tiles-20180327/), without explicitly telling it, but shown in the images, I should have *Cast* available.
- According to [this](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/add-google-cast-button-your-quick-settings-tiles-any-phone-no-root-needed-0181286/), availability of *Cast* is "largely dependent on your phone's OEM skin... the Google Cast button... has been exclusive to Nexus and Pixel devices, even though other phones have the requisite software to use it."
  One should install [Quick Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesestito.ntiles) to be able to add the icon.
  This opposes the implicit description above.

Note 2:
I am not certain about the relation between this *Cast* icon, *Quick connect*, *Smart view*, Windows 10 Connect, and the following 2 icons.

[image]
[image]

Note 3:
I actually mean to cast from Android to PC without a WiFi router, but that is a separate story.

Comment: Related on [XDA Devs](https://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/help/mod-to-cast-tile-quick-settings-menu-t3400348)

Comment: @AndrewT. - Didn't find much help there. Moreover, it started on June 2016, [prior to Nougat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_7.0_Nougat_(API_24)).

Comment: Tried [reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187683)?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that there's a very high possibility that Samsung doesn't have Cast on their quick settings since manufacturers are free to customize their devices. Instead, they provide "Quick Connect" or "Smart View" which is too specific for Samsung-related devices